# how to slow down the execution of a code in C?

Tags: c, linux, opengl

I am self-learning openGL in C on a linux machine. Here is my basic code for drawing a circle using a loop. I would like to slow down the execution of this program so that I can see the formation of the circle point by point. (hope I am able to convey properly what  I mean).

```
#include <GL/glut.h>    // Header File For The GLUT Library
#include<math.h>

void main (int argc, char*argv[])
{
    float y, x=-0.75;

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200,150);
    glutInitWindowSize(500,500);
    glutCreateWindow (argv[0]);

    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);  // choosing the background color
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);      // setting the color buffer to background color
    glColor3f(1,1,1);
    glPointSize(2);

    for (x=-0.75;x <= 0.75; x=x+0.005){
        y = sqrt(0.5625 -(x*x));

        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glVertex2f(x,y);
            glVertex2f(x,-y);
        glEnd();

    }



    glFlush();

    glutMainLoop();

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop, executing the drawing commands may run at a time, when the window hasn't been placed on the screen yet. As a general rule, you should always draw from the drawing handler and from nowhere else.

Regarding your request to "slow down" the process. You can use [usleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) for that. However this will also make your program unresponsive for as long drawing takes to execute.

Also, and **important** OpenGL uses an asynchronous operation model, i.e. all drawing operations are queued up and executed only after the queue is flushed. So to see the drawing progress with a well defined timing, you must wait for the previous step to finish. Use `glFinish` for that.

Last but not least, to actually see the progress happening you must draw to the front buffer (of a double buffered window) or use a single buffered window. Now there's a catch: If you're using a compositing window manager, the window's contents update may be delayed until a buffer swap is executed. Of course this won't happen on a single buffered window. Which effectively means, that composition and single buffered drawing don't mix very well.

The only really robust way to implement this is not to delay the drawing itself, but to redraw the entire scene, again, and again in the usual animation loop. And doing that you terminate the drawing process one step later at each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

The circle won't be drawn one point at a time; all the commands together will be used to create the circle, which will then be shown instantly via a buffer flip. That's just how OpenGL works.

I'm tempted to talk about various issues with this code, but I'll just mention that it's way better to use a single glBegin/glEnd pair to enclose all your points.

Comment: Why could he not draw a part of the triangle and flip?

Comment: @self - which triangle would that be? I don't see any.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill I changed the code to a single loop now. thanks for the suggestion. didn't see it that way. Is it possible to animate a single point on the 'circular path' to get the effect I am seeking?

Comment: @enhzflep Lapsus, replace triangle with circle.

Comment: Yes, you could write this to be animated.  You would write a glut display function, and in that function, control the upper limit of the for loop with a variable. Increment the variable each time the function is called , so the next time will draw more of the circle .

Comment: @self. Yes, of course he could. But that would not be *this program*, that would be a different program, as I described in my comments. There's no way to slow down *this program* and watch it draw, although indeed, you can write a *different program* which animates the drawing. Now, let's undo the downvote, please.

Comment: @self. Because a flip may clobber the contents of the back buffer. So you'd had to draw everything up to the given stage, plus the stage itself.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill: OpenGL doesn't know about double buffering at all. The windowing system does. And it is perfectly possible to switch to single buffered operation, or to draw selectively to the front buffer.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill *Now, let's undo the downvote, please.* I can't even if i wanted to. Try no to get too attached to votes, remember it is not I who votes on your answer but the whole community. I guess your answer just isn't good enough to convince the majority of people to vote.